# Vercel - Node.js v18.18.2 Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

Tags: node.js, github, vercel, sveltekit

When I deploy I get :

```
Error: 500 /grake
To suppress or handle this error, implement `handleHttpError` in https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#prerender
    at file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/core/config/options.js:202:13
    at file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/core/postbuild/prerender.js:64:25
    at save (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/core/postbuild/prerender.js:399:4)
    at visit (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/core/postbuild/prerender.js:232:3)
Emitted 'error' event on Worker instance at:
    at [kOnErrorMessage] (node:internal/worker:300:10)
    at [kOnMessage] (node:internal/worker:311:37)
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> (node:internal/worker:212:57)
    at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:757:20)
    at exports.emitMessage (node:internal/per_context/messageport:23:28)
Node.js v18.18.2
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

**Steps taken**

- Integrated my Github repo with sole branch of `main`.
- Am the sole owner and my credentials for logging into `Vercel` are the same as the ones I use to perform the git updates.
- Installed the `Vercel` CLI and performed `vercel --prod` from my root dir
- I deleted my `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and reinstalled the modules via `npm i` and `npm run build`
- I also configured `ci = False` as my Environment Variable in Vercel.

Configured my package.json as so:

```
{
    "name": "game",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./jsconfig.json",
        "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./jsconfig.json --watch",
        "test": "npm run test:integration && npm run test:unit",
        "lint": "prettier --check . && eslint .",
        "format": "prettier --write .",
        "test:integration": "playwright test",
        "test:unit": "vitest"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@fontsource/fira-mono": "^4.5.10",
        "@neoconfetti/svelte": "^1.0.0",
        "@playwright/test": "^1.28.1",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^3.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "^2.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^3.0.0",
        "@types/eslint": "8.56.0",
        "eslint": "^8.56.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte": "^2.35.1",
        "prettier": "^3.1.1",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^3.1.2",
        "svelte": "^4.2.7",
        "svelte-check": "^3.6.0",
        "typescript": "^5.0.0",
        "vite": "^5.0.3",
        "vitest": "^1.0.0"
    }, 
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/adapter-vercel": "^4.0.4",
        "openai": "^4.24.3",
        "vercel": "^33.1.0"
    }
}
```

Why is the deployment failing ?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a `+page.svelte` under my `/grake` folder. Added it and it resolved the issue.

SvelteKit uses a file-based routing system and it requires a +page.svelte for SvelteKit v0 and v1 as of today.